How to Implement "Append to Body" for @shentao/vue-multiselect 2.1.6 in Vue 2.6
I am using Vue 2.6 with @shentao/vue-multiselect version 2.1.6. I've created a reusable component where I bind all props and events to the multiselect component. Here's my code:
Here is the component:
<template>
<div>
 <multiselect
        :id="'select-' + new Date()"
        :ref="'multiselect-' + new Date()"
        v-model="localValue"
        :multiple="multiple"
        :searchable="searchable"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        :close-on-select="closeOnSelect"
        :track-by="trackBy || valueField"
        :label="label || textField"
        :clear-on-select="clearOnSelect"
        :hide-selected="hideSelected"
        :allow-empty="allowEmpty"
        :reset-after="resetAfter"
        :taggable="taggable"
        :tag-placeholder="tagPlaceholder"
        :options="options"
        :tag-position="tagPosition"
        :max="max"
        :options-limit="optionsLimit"
        :group-label="groupLabel"
        :group-select="groupSelect"
        :block-keys="blockKeys"
        :internal-search="internalSearch"
        :preserve-search="preserveSearch"
        :preselect-first="preselectFirst"
        :prevent-autofocus="preventAutofocus"
        :limit="limit"
        :limit-text="limitText"
        :disabled="disabled"
        :open-direction="openDirection"
        :max-height="maxHeight"
        :show-no-options="showNoOptions"
        :show-no-results="showNoResults"
        @select="handleSelect"
        @remove="handleRemove"
        @search-change="handleSearchChange"
        @tag="handleTag"
        @open="handleOpen"
        @close="handleClose"
      />
</div>
</template>

Problem:
The vue-multiselect version I am using does not support the appendToBody feature natively. As a result, dropdown menus are constrained within the component's container, causing layout issues in some scenarios (e.g., dropdowns cut off or overlapping).
I attempted to implement a custom solution by manually moving the dropdown element to the <body>, but this caused misalignment issues (e.g., the dropdown does not align with the input box).
Question:

What is the best way to implement an append to body functionality for this specific version of @shentao/vue-multiselect?
How can I ensure proper alignment and avoid positioning issues when appending the dropdown to the ?

Additional Notes:

I am looking for a solution compatible with Vue 2.6 and @shentao/vue-multiselect 2.1.6.
If there are alternative libraries or hacks that work seamlessly, I am open to suggestions.


Hey, please check this issue on github: https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/618 in that issue some of contributor has proposed some of custom solution you can look. There is one custom directive solution: https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/618#issuecomment-2401545741
